# left_join function between x and y data frames returns more rows than the first data frame in r

Tags: r, merge, dplyr, left-join

I have two data frames with the following dimension:

```
dim(x)
8637   133

dim (y)
8113   26
```

I am trying to merge x and y by one common column in x and y. I am using left_join function from dplyr package.

```
df <- dplyr::left_join(x, y, by = "col1")
```

The number of rows in the merged data is more than the first data frame(x).

```
nrow(df)
8666
```

What I would expect to get after merging x and y is a new data frame with all rows from x as well as all columns from both x and y. I guess this is what left_join in dplyr is supposed to do but there is something wrong in the result of left_join(). Any idea how I can fix the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to be sure without a reproducible example, but probably the "y" data frame has duplicated values in "col1".

Example:

```
x <- data.frame(col0 = 1:3, col1 = letters[1:3])
y <- data.frame(col1 = c("a", "a", "b"), col2 = 4:6)
left_join(x, y, by = "col1")

  col0 col1 col2
1    1    a    4
2    1    a    5
3    2    b    6
4    3    c   NA
```

Although both data frames have 3 rows, the resultant join has 4 rows, and that is perfecty right! Maybe you need to remove the duplicates from the "y" data frame?

Answer (score 1):

Using `merge` from `base R`

```
merge(x, y, all.x = TRUE, by = "col1")
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue some months ago. Today I again had the same issue. But this time I solve my problem in another way. There were "Na" values in the column that I would have liked to merge data frames based on it. So the output of inner_join() and left_join() functions from dplyr package was 3 times bigger than my data frames. I removed the "NA" values in the common column between my two dfs and then I got the correct dimension of the resulted data frame.

I just want to answer this question with another solution that might be helpful for someone who has the same question. 
Thanks.